# Extend table of varchar with a varchar

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to create a table of varchar array like this:

```
DECLARE
        lna_poi_list   fls_number_table := fls_number_table();
        lsa_poi_list   fls_varchar_table := fls_varchar_table();
        ls_poi_list    varchar;
BEGIN
FOR i IN 1..lna_poi_list.COUNT 
LOOP  
ls_poi_list := calling a function that returns a varchar and takes
lna_poi_list(i) as param;
lsa_poi_list.extend(ls_poi_list);   
END LOOP
END;
```

After this I just want to return lsa_poi_list array but I'm getting some

> character to number conversion error

Any ideas is much appreaciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#CJAIJHEI), `extend` takes optional numeric arguments:

> The `EXTEND` method has these forms:
>
> `EXTEND` appends one null element to the collection.
>
> `EXTEND(n)` appends n null elements to the collection.
>
> `EXTEND(n,i)` appends n copies of the ith element to the collection.

To assign a new element, extend the collection, and then assign the value:

```
  lsa_poi_list.extend;
  lsa_poi_list(lsa_poi_list.COUNT) := ls_poi_list;
```

Referencing `count` means you're populating the last (new, null) element in the array.

If you're always adding one varhar (varchar2?) element for each element in the number array, you can size it once before the loop instead, which would be slightly more efficient, e.g:

```
DECLARE
  lna_poi_list   sys.odcinumberlist := sys.odcinumberlist();
  lsa_poi_list   sys.odcivarchar2list := sys.odcivarchar2list();
  ls_poi_list    varchar2(10);
BEGIN
  lna_poi_list.extend(3);
  lsa_poi_list.extend(lna_poi_list.COUNT);

  FOR i IN 1..lna_poi_list.COUNT 
  LOOP  
    ls_poi_list := 'x'; -- from some function
    lsa_poi_list(i) := ls_poi_list;
  END LOOP;
END;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Yes always adding one varchar2, yeah this definetly looks better